# Application request routing and load balancing

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, routing, arr

I use Application request routing in my farm environnement.

I got 2 ARR server and 2 IIS server in my farm. I configure my routing to load balance request even to my iis server, but when i look worker process in my farm server, only one server receive all the request and the other server is idle.

Could someone tell my if i am rigth or not but ARR suppose to load balance the request even on all my farm server if i configure it to do that rigth ?

My load balance configuration is Weigthed total traffic,(even distribution).
My server affinity is set to Client affinity, Use host name, ignore subdomain

Comment: In your server farm, double click Load Balance.  What algorithm are you using?

Comment: Actually is Least response time

Answer (score 0):

I could make a rather long post, detailing all the possibilities causing this, or I could give you an extremely useful link that walks one through the entire process.  I'll do the second thing!

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120628235113/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/17/iis7-load-balancing-routing-module-now-available.aspx)

If you find that you cannot solve your problem with the steps listed in this article then feel free to respond with what problems still plague you.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Weighted round robin" and fire at least 2 requests then check whether your servers receive the requests or not.